# Customize sizing in _variables.scss

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm Looking to customize [sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) to include more than just the default 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100%. It says in the documentation "Width and height utilities are generated from the $sizes Sass map in _variables.scss ... Modify those values as you need to generate different utilities here."

I can't find the $sizes Sass map anywhere in [_variable.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss), and I'm not too sure what the correct format is. Can someone please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the branch from `master` to `v4-dev` showed me that `$sizes` was defined there at one point but got removed/moved somewhere else.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L152-L164

```
// This variable affects the `.h-*` and `.w-*` classes.
$sizes: () !default;
// stylelint-disable-next-line scss/dollar-variable-default
$sizes: map-merge(
  (
    25: 25%,
    50: 50%,
    75: 75%,
    100: 100%,
    auto: auto
  ),
  $sizes
);
```